# On a rearrangement inequality

Tags: measure-theory

Let us consider a measure space $(\mathbb{N},\Sigma_{\mathbb{N}},\mu)$, where
$$
\Sigma_{\mathbb{N}}=\{Q\in 2^{\mathbb{N}} \colon Q \text{ is finite}\}
$$ 
and 
$$
\mu(Q)=\sum_{n\in Q}n.
$$
Suppose $a=\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $b=\{b_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are sequences which tend to zero as $n\to\infty$. Then one can compute their non-increasing rearrangements $a^*$ and $b^*$. Now comes my question. Is it true that
$$
(a\cdot b)^*_n \lesssim a^*_n b^*_n \quad?
$$

Comment: First, it seems to me that $\Sigma_{\mathbb{N}}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra. Second, what do you mean by $\lesssim$?

Comment: Ok. It is just a setup. Let $\Sigma_{\mathbb{N}}=2^{\mathbb{N}}$.  The sign $\lesssim$ means less or equal up to constant

Comment: Then it seems to me that the question is independent of $\mu$, correct?

Comment: Well. if $\mu(Q)=\sum\limits_{n\in Q}1$, then the inequality is true. This is a well-known fact. But our the measure $\mu$ defined above is an atomic measure. Where all atoms have different measure. In my opinion, this is  a weird measure space. I would say unusual.

Comment: It seems to me that you are asking whether there is some constant $C$ such that $\gamma_n^*\leq C a_n^*b_n^*$, where $\gamma_n=a_nb_n$. As far as I can tell, this is true, with $C=1$. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Define a rearrangement of sequence for non-counting measure $\mu$

Comment: Take $n_1=\min \{n|a_n=\max_j a_j\}$. Take $n_2=\min \{n|a_n=\max_{j\neq n_1} a_j\}$. Proceed by induction to obtain the non-increasing rearrangement $a_j^*=a_{n_j}$. If you had a different rearrangement in mind, you should make that clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19147/discussion-between-rauan-akylzhanov-and-user161825).